# Why is a low threshold necessary for generating an action potential?

Tags: neuroscience

On page 32 of "Principles of Neural Science," it sates that, "...the initial segment of the axon has the highest density of voltage-sensitive Na+ channels and therefore the lowest threshold for generating an action potential..."

Comment: The quote you write already has an answer to one "why" question. Can you explain which "why" question you want answered? "Why" can be asked at many levels of analysis and it is ambiguous which level is intended.

Comment: Is this the reference?: *Kandel, E. (2013). Principles of neural science. New York: McGraw-Hill.*

Comment: Yes, that is the reference.